# Spring Batch: One item in, multiple items processed, one item out

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and I'm not sure how to best structure the solution to my problem.

I have input lines that define a number of sub-items to create and then process, which then need to be re-assembled into one result.

A simplified example: For each `GroundhogDay` that is read, a list of `GroundhogDayVariations` must be created. `GroundhogDayVariations` are processed in parallel to create a collection of `GroundhogDayVariationOutcomes`, which need to be condensed into an `GroundhogDayAverageOutcome`.

What is the most sensible way to accomplish this in Spring Batch?

Comment: Is it one-to-one relation between , `GroundhogDayVariations` & `GroundhogDayVariationOutcomes` or one-to-many ? Your statement -- **GroundhogDayVariations are processed in parallel** is something that is confusing me. Please try to explain with a flow diagram to make it more clear .

Comment: I'm not sure the chunk-oriented processing model provided by Spring Batch is suitable for your use case.